# Securing Raspberry Pi 3B+ Web Server with NAS

Tags: web-server, debian, apache-httpd, security

I have been researching about the security threats to a web server. It makes me want to secure my own on my Raspbian OS system. What are the list of things that are recommended or optional to install or configure on the server.

I currently have:

- ClamAV
- Fail2ban
- Apache httpd
- ufw/gufw

Also, provide me a way that I can configure these packages to make it as secure as possible including SSH as I will be working on it remotely.

Comment: Your question is too broad. I can imagine a while book about securing Apache alone.